# jQuery().append is working but .html is not working on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using WordPress. After getting response I'm using jQuery().append(response) .Its working fine. Problem is that it is generating multiple div .That's why I need to use html or innerHtml .But it is not working. Though I'm getting response back from server.

```
        function get_chat_history() {
            //var doc = document.getElementById("show-chat-div-text");
            document.getElementById("show-chat-div-text").lastElementChild;
            var id_of_incoming_chat_user=document.getElementById("show-chat-div-[![enter image description here][1]][1]text").lastElementChild;
            var id_incoming_chat_user;
            if (id_of_incoming_chat_user!=null) {
             id_incoming_chat_user= id_of_incoming_chat_user.getAttribute('class');

            }
            else (id_of_incoming_chat_user===null)
            {

                id_incoming_chat_user=document.getElementById("show-chat-div-text").getElementsByTagName("Div")[0].getAttribute('class');


            }
            if(id_incoming_chat_user==="user-hide")
            {

                id_incoming_chat_user=document.getElementById("show-chat-div-text").getElementsByTagName("Div")[1].getAttribute('class');

            }


            cur_user = '<?php echo get_current_user_id() ;?>';
            var message = document.getElementById("myInput").value;
            var listitem="";
            var postdata = {action: "navid_history_ajax_call",
                            param_user_to_chat: id_incoming_chat_user,
                            param_main_user:cur_user,
                            message:message                                                     
                            };
            jQuery.post(ajaxurl, postdata, function (response) {

                            //jQuery("#show-chat-div-text").html=response;//not working
                          //  jQuery("#show-chat-div-text").append(response);//Working 
                                                
                            console.log(response);
                            chatBox.scrollTop = chatBox.scrollHeight;
                                 });                 

        }
        setInterval(get_chat_history, 5000);
```

Comment: Try: `jQuery("#show-chat-div-text").html(response);` ?

Comment: Hi, this `jQuery("#show-chat-div-text").html=response;` should be `jQuery("#show-chat-div-text").html(response);`

Comment: I am not sure why you are saying :P that doesn't work . But , other option will be using `jQuery("#show-chat-div-text").empty()` and then use `append()` or use `jQuery("#show-chat-div-text").html("")` then use `append()`.

Comment: @swati Thats a good idea to use jQuery("#show-chat-div-text").empty() then append().

Comment: @Sharee thanks. Looks like it was the problem .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap the response within brackets.

Ex:

```
jQuery("#show-chat-div-text").html(response);
```